# Flutter TextFormField with icon on container with height

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to recreate this search input but I'm having troubles in keeping it that small, if I add the prefixIcon the height increases and I can't seem to control it.

[image]

Here's what I have right now.
**I'm using a row because I will need to add a button after the input field as well, but that's for later.**

[image]

```
Widget _buildSearch() => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          color: Color(0xFF131313),
          height: 50.0,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ), // icon is 48px widget.
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Search artist, genre, playlist',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Hello!You can Try using Icon widget right in the same row.

Comment: That did it, thanks... feeling dumb lol

Comment: Flexible(
                flex: 2,    this could be a issue

Comment: use `prefix` instead of `prefixIcon`. That's better than an extra widget in the row, because tapping on the icon will focus the search input.

Answer (score 32):

adjust the content padding for the textfield and wrap your icon in padding widget since its input type is Widget

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20), // add padding to adjust text
          isDense: true,
          hintText: "Email",
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15), // add padding to adjust icon
            child: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
          ),

    );
```

this is the output of above code

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

you can adjust image size like this

```
prefixIcon: new Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only( top: 15, left: 5, right: 0, bottom: 15),
   child: new SizedBox(
            height: 4,
            child: Image.asset(imgname),
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `height` to your `hintStyle` to avoid this:

```
hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, color: Colors.white, height: 3),
```

About [height](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html) in [TextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html):

> The height of this text span, as a multiple of the font size.
>
> When height is null or omitted, the line height will be determined by
>   the font's metrics directly, which may differ from the fontSize. When
>   height is non-null, the line height of the span of text will be a
>   multiple of fontSize and be exactly fontSize * height logical pixels
>   tall.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ListTile*, the icon put in *leading* and *TextFormField* put in *Title*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: AppTheme.fontName,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: AppTheme.deactivatedText,
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `prefixIcon` property if you wanna controll the details, it's not useful.

This is what i do:

```dart
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  height: 50.0,
  color: const Color(0xff131313),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            hintText: 'Search artist, genre, playlist',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 11.0,
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: The first one is from my code, and the second one from yours.]

The first one is from my code, and the second one from yours. You can change the paddings as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this method i think u like it,
you just have to add the FocusNode and controller by urself...

Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: parentWidth * .04,
              right: parentWidth * .04,
              top: parentHeight * .02,
              bottom: parentHeight * .02),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: parentWidth * .05, right: parentWidth * .05),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(25.0))),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    focusNode: _searchingFocus,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    controller: _searchController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
                      _searchingFocus.unfocus();
                    },
                    // controller: _isSearching,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: StringEn.ALL_CATEGORY_TEXT,
                        hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                            color: CommonColor.MENU_BTN_COLOR.withOpacity(.4),
                            fontSize: categoryText - 4,
                            fontFamily: CommonWidget.AVENIR_BOOK)),
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        color: CommonColor.MENU_BTN_COLOR,
                        fontSize: categoryText - 3,
                        fontFamily: CommonWidget.AVENIR_BOOK),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: parentWidth * 0.0),
                  child: new Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    size: parentWidth * 0.06,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```